# Accessing method from Application class in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created an application class in Kotlin. I need to access a method that returns a variable from anywhere in my application. 
The problem is I am not able to access that method from other parts of the program. 
I am able to access when code is written in Java , but when code is written in Kotlin,then the  method in Application class is not accessible. 
Please find below code for reference:

class MyRetroApplication : Application() {

```
lateinit var apiComponent:APIComponent
companion object {
    var ctx: Context? = null
}
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ctx = applicationContext
    apiComponent = initDaggerComponent()

}

fun getMyComponent(): APIComponent {
    return apiComponent
}

fun initDaggerComponent():APIComponent{
    apiComponent =   DaggerAPIComponent
        .builder()
        .aPIModule(APIModule(APIURL.BASE_URL))
        .build()
    return  apiComponent

} }
```

In the above code how to access the function getMyComponent()  globally in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach-1:**

Put `getMyComponent()` inside companion

```
companion object {
    var ctx: Context? = null
    private lateinit var apiComponent: APIComponent

    fun getMyComponent(): APIComponent = apiComponent
}
```

And then from anywhere:

```
MyRetroApplication.getMyComponent()
```

**Approach-2:**

Change the type of `ctx` to `MyRetroApplication` instead of `Context` and then from anywhere:

```
MyRetroApplication.ctx.getMyComponent()
```

**Approach-3:**

Same as approach 2 but in a formal way. Create `getInstance()` inside companion and pass `ctx` (private)

```
companion object {
    private lateinit var ctx: MyRetroApplication

    fun getInstance(): MyRetroApplication {
        return ctx
    }
}
```

And then from anywhere:

```
MyRetroApplication.getInstance().getMyComponent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `getMyComponen()` inside companion like @Md. Asaduzzaman answer or use applicationContext to access it like -

```
(application as MyRetroApplication).getMyComponent()
```

or

```
(applicationContext as MyRetroApplication).getMyComponent()
```

or

```
MyRetroApplication.ctx?.let{
(it as MyRetroApplication).getMyComponent()  //by your companion app context
}
```